# Generic type conversion in C

Tags: c, generics, c-preprocessor, x-macros

I have a list of data types (`STANDARD_TYPES`). I would like to automatically (using X macros) create functions that would convert from one of those type to another.

I have the following code:

```
#define STANDARD_TYPES(macro)   \
    macro(char)                 \
    macro(uchar)                \
    macro(schar)                \
    macro(short)                \
    macro(ushort)               \
    macro(int)                  \
    macro(uint)                 \
    macro(long)                 \
    macro(ulong)                \
    macro(longlong)             \
    macro(ulonglong)            \
    macro(float)                \
    macro(double)               \
    macro(longdouble)


#define Y(to_type, from_type)                                                                                                    \
    case TYPE_##from_type:                                          \
        ((struct result_##to_type *)result)->value =                \
            (to_type)((struct result_##from_type *)result)->value;  \
        break;
            
#define X(to_type)                                                                                                      \
void convert_to_##to_type(struct result *result)    \
{                                                   \
    switch (result->type) {                         \
        Y(to_type, long)                            \
    }                                               \
                                                    \
    return result;                                  \
}

STANDARD_TYPES(X)
#undef X
#undef Y
```

`struct result_X` is generated for every type and looks like:

```
struct result {
    enum type type;
};

struct result_char {
    enum type type;
    char value;
};

struct result_long {
    enum type type;
    long value;
};
```

With the above code example I can generate functions to convert from `char` data type to any other data type. For example, `long` output for the above code example would be:

```
void convert_to_long(struct result *result)
{
    switch (result->type) {
    case TYPE_char:
        ((struct result_long *)result)->value = (long)((struct result_char *)result)->value;
        break;
    }
}
```

With what can I replace `Y(to_type, char)` code or more parts of the code to make it generate conversion functions between all defined data types?

EDIT:

```
enum type {
    TYPE_char,
    TYPE_uchar,
    TYPE_schar,
    ...
    TYPE_long,
    ...
};
```

EDIT2:

To clear up some things I shall explain briefly what my code is trying to accomplish. On the user side, that is whoever is using my code, they are executing some math operations and when done they write the result to the `struct result *result` along with the type of the result and the value.

My code shall then convert value of the `struct result *result` from the type contained in `struct result *result` to the requested type which can be any of the standard types.

```
void convert_result(struct result *result, enum type new_type)
{
    switch (new_type) {
    case TYPE_char:
        convert_to_char(result);
        break;
    ...
    case TYPE_long:
        convert_to_long(result);
        break;
};
```

Comment: Why not just use a [tagged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/3fe7db9f-5803-4dc4-9d14-5425d3f5461f) union like [VARIANT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-variant) does?

Comment: @Dmitry Because the types can be extended beyond standard. User can define any type they want. That is also the reason why the `struct result`is the way it is.

Comment: Pointer punning invokes undefined behaviour. Your code may work or not as usually when UB is invoked.

Comment: The whole thing looks like it does a simple thing in a complicated way. Why do you need a function to convert from one data type to another? What's wrong with built in conversions, i.e. implicit conversions and casts?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. how are you going to pune byte array to double using casts?

Comment: @0___________ I don't see any byte arrays in this code. All I see are simple casts of `char` (note not `char*`) to `long` etc. The only type punning involved is between different brands of the `result` struct.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I have a function somewhere else that writes result of some math operation to `struct result *result`. This `result` is then passed to my function where I need to convert the `result` (it can be any type) to requested type (it can be any type).

Comment: Your function generated by X macro returns void but has a nonempty return statement. I think you meant to write `struct result *` as the return type there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is a way to get the desired behavior of applying the [X Macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) within itself, since recursive macro replacement is suppressed by C 2018 6.10.3.4 2. However, if you define two X Macros, this can be done:

```
#define ApplyToTypes(macro) \
    macro(char)  \
    macro(short) \
    macro(int)

#define ApplyToTypes2(ToType, macro) \
    macro(ToType, char)  \
    macro(ToType, short) \
    macro(ToType, int)


#define Case(ToType, FromType)                                     \
    case TYPE_##FromType:                                          \
        ((struct result_##ToType *) result)->value =               \
            (ToType) ((struct result_##FromType *) result)->value; \
        break;

#define Routine(ToType) \
    void ConvertTo##ToType(struct result *result) \
    {                                             \
        switch (result->type)                     \
        {                                         \
            ApplyToTypes2(ToType, Case)           \
        }                                         \
    }

ApplyToTypes(Routine)
```

This is replaced by (with manual formatting added for readability):

```
void ConvertTochar(struct result *result)
{
    switch (result->type)
    {
        case TYPE_char: ((struct result_char *) result)->value = (char) ((struct result_char *) result)->value;
            break;
        case TYPE_short: ((struct result_char *) result)->value = (char) ((struct result_short *) result)->value;
            break;
        case TYPE_int: ((struct result_char *) result)->value = (char) ((struct result_int *) result)->value;
            break;
    }
}
void ConvertToshort(struct result *result)
{
    switch (result->type)
    {
        case TYPE_char: ((struct result_short *) result)->value = (short) ((struct result_char *) result)->value;
            break;
        case TYPE_short: ((struct result_short *) result)->value = (short) ((struct result_short *) result)->value;
            break;
        case TYPE_int: ((struct result_short *) result)->value = (short) ((struct result_int *) result)->value;
            break;
    }
}
void ConvertToint(struct result *result)
{
    switch (result->type)
    {
        case TYPE_char: ((struct result_int *) result)->value = (int) ((struct result_char *) result)->value;
            break;
        case TYPE_short: ((struct result_int *) result)->value = (int) ((struct result_short *) result)->value;
            break;
        case TYPE_int: ((struct result_int *) result)->value = (int) ((struct result_int *) result)->value;
            break;
    }
}
```

To give this code behavior defined by the C standard, you could define a union containing all the `result` structures, so that C 2018 6.5.2.3 6 would apply.<sup>1</sup> However, it may be nicer simply to define one structure containing a union and rewrite the code to match:

```
struct result
{
    enum type type;
    union
    {
        char  char_value;
        short short_value;
        int   int_value;
        …
    };
};
```

For example:

```
#define ApplyToTypes(macro) \
    macro(char)  \
    macro(short) \
    macro(int)

#define ApplyToTypes2(ToType, macro) \
    macro(ToType, char)  \
    macro(ToType, short) \
    macro(ToType, int)

#define DeclareEnumConstants(Type)  Type##Enum,
enum type { ApplyToTypes(DeclareEnumConstants) };

#define DeclareMember(Type) Type Type##Value;
struct result
{
    enum type type;
    union
    {
        ApplyToTypes(DeclareMember)
    };
};

#define Case(ToType, FromType)                                    \
    case FromType##Enum:                                          \
        result->ToType##Value = (ToType) result->FromType##Value; \
        break;

#define Routine(ToType) \
    void ConvertTo##ToType(struct result *result) \
    {                                             \
        switch (result->type)                     \
        {                                         \
            ApplyToTypes2(ToType, Case)           \
        }                                         \
    }

ApplyToTypes(Routine)
```

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> C 2018 6.5.2.3 6 says:

> … if a union contains several structures that share a common initial sequence…, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the completed type of the union is visible…

Also relevant is C 2018 67.2.1 16:

> … A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks. I've used multiple structs because:

    1) I wanted to save memory. Dont want to create a 128 bytes `long double` if I only need 1 byte `bool`.
    2) I wanted an option for the user to define a custom `struct result_custom { enum type type; /* custom members */ };`

I guess for the 2) the workaround could be to have a void* inside the union. And 128bytes is not that much.

If you have any more clarifications regarding 1) and 2) I'd be happy to hear them. I will accept this answer later today when I get the chance to test it out.

Thanks!

Comment: @user1806687 Regarding your point 1), i.e. save memory.... For this to work the caller of `ConvertTo` must provide a pointer to memory sufficiently large to hold the largest target-struct. If you want to be able handle all conversions then all objects must be of the largest size, I would assume.

Comment: @SupportUkraine If the caller will only work with int's it might be inefficient to allocate long double memory.

For my case it is fine and will use the union approach.

Comment: @user1806687 that's true so your idea is to have a restriction on your convert function to that tells that it is the callers responsibility the the passed pointer points to sufficient memory for holding the target type - otherwise it will be undefined behavior... is that it?

Comment: The quoted C 2018 67.2.1 makes it clear that a pointer to e.g. `struct result` may be converted to a pointer to `enum type` (as `enum type` is the first member. As far as I can see the ides is that the caller will have e.g. a `struct_result_char` and convert it to `struct result` when calling the convert function. Even if both `struct result` and `struct result_char` has a `enum type` as first member it seems to be a different conversion that addressed by C 2018 67.2.1. Am I wrong? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Also looking at `((struct result_int *) result)->value = (int) ((struct result_char *) result)->value;` makes me wonder if  C 2018 67.2.1 really allows that. First of all `result` is not a pointer to a first member. But even if `result`actually was a "first member" pointer isn't it still a problem that `result` is casted to 2 different pointer types? After as I understand  C 2018 67.2.1 only say that you can go to first member and back to the original struct type. I don't think it allows going to any struct type having the same first member. Am I wrong? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @SupportUkraine: Consider a union with all the indicated structure types as members, and a `p` that points to it. Then `(struct result *) p` points to the `struct result` member of the union, by 6.7.2.1 16, and, even if it was not the last member stored, 6.5.2.3 6 allows us to inspect its `type` member. That tells us which member the union actually holds, and then `(struct result_int *) p` (or whatever type) points to that member, and `((struct result_int *) p)->value` is a defined read of the value of its `value` member…

Comment: … After that `(struct result_char *) p` points to a different member, but it is used for storing, so it updates the union to hold that new member.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Yes. It is the callers responsibility to allocate enough memory to hold the largest type.

Comment: This works for all types but not for bool type. Because bool gets macro expanded to _Bool meaning the result structure would have to contain _BoolValue member but I want it to contain boolValue member. Is this doable?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well, I was refering to the first part of the answer where there is no union (like in OPs question)

Comment: I will use _Bool instead of bool type.

Answer (score -1):

Your code invokes undefined behaviour as you break strict aliasing rules.

To "convert" (it called type punning) char array to other type (assuming that the car array contains the correct byte representation of the destination type) toy need to `memcpy` it. Also your strange enums will not work as well.

example:

```
long long puneToLongLong(const char *buff)
{
    long long result;
    memcpy(&result, buff, sizeof(result));
    return result;
}

double puneToDouble(const char *buff)
{
    double result;
    memcpy(&result, buff, sizeof(result));
    return result;
}

int puneTo(const char *buff)
{
    int result;
    memcpy(&result, buff, sizeof(result));
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    char cd[sizeof(double)];
    char cll[sizeof(long long)];
    char ci[sizeof(int)];

    memcpy(cd, &(double){5.45676545}, sizeof(cd));
    memcpy(cll, &(long long){453676457654}, sizeof(cll));
    memcpy(ci, &(long long){-12454354}, sizeof(ci));

    printf("%f\n", puneToDouble(cd));
    printf("%lld\n", puneToLongLong(cll));
    printf("%i\n", puneToInt(ci));
}
```

Comment: My example above works. What rules am I breaking? I dont understand.

Comment: @user1806687 you do pointer punning. It is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user1806687 [See](https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8). Undefined behaviour typically appears to work, until it doesn't.

Comment: (a) This does not address the posted question about macro replacement or “automatically” defining functions. (b) It falsely states aliasing rules are violated. The code in the question does not contain any aliasing violation. The code shown could be used with no aliasing violations if a suitable union were defined, per C 2018 6.5.2.3 6. (c) The code shown in the answer does not provide any way of implementing the conversions the question requests; it appears to be a misunderstanding of the problem to be solved.